# How do i install drush for a drupal site which is on shared hosting?

Tags: drush

I have a shared hosting account on which i have created sites using joomla 2.5 and drupal 7.

I want to use drush to apply patches to existing modules for my drupal 7 site.

Can any one guide me as to how can i install this drush and use it for these drupal 7 sites on my shared hosting ?

Step by Step Guide would be highly appreciated (New here)

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

When I google "[install drush on shared hosting](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=install+drush+on+shared+hosting)", the two top hits are exactly what you are looking for.

1. [Learning How to Install Drush on a Non-Admin Rights Server](http://www.mediacurrent.com/blog/learning-how-install-drush-non-admin-rights-server)
2. [Installing Drush on Shared Hosting Accounts](http://drupal.org/node/1181480)

Answer (score 2):

Update: There is a complete github project now https://github.com/theodorosploumis/drush-installer.

Assuming that you have **ssh access** to the server and no sudo permissions.

Also, there must be `curl` and `zip` installed. Otherwise you have to change the related commands according to your tools.

Drush now is installed through Composer so we need to install Composer before Drush.

```
# 1. Login to the server from your local machine with ssh
$ ssh USER@SERVER
$ cd ~

# 2. Use Bash as command line (if you like you can use your own CL too!)
$ chsh -s $(which bash) $USER

# 3. Install Composer
$ mkdir ~/bin
$ curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=bin

# 4. Download Drush files (we are in our home folder)

# 4.1 Git method (recommended). After this go to step 5
$ cd ~
$ git clone git@github.com/drush-ops/drush.git
$ cd drush
$ git checkout 6.x

# 4.2 Alternatively, if you don't have git, 
# download the files with wget. Currently stable version is 6.x
# Notice that you need Drush 7.x to be able to work with Drupal 8.x
$ wget https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/archive/6.x.zip

# Unzip it and rename the folder to /drush
$ unzip 6.x.zip
$ rm 6.x.zip
$ mv ~/drush-6.x ~/drush

# 5. Make the drush folder executable by current USER
$ chmod u+x ~/drush/drush

# 6. Install Drush from Composer
$ cd ~/drush
$ php ~/bin/composer.phar install

# 7. Add alias drush to .bash_profile
$ echo "alias drush='~/drush/drush'" > ~/.bash_profile

# 8. Source the changed .bash_profile or restart ssh session
$ source ~/.bash_profile
```

I have created 2 simple bash scripts for this task.

- [bash script without Git](https://gist.github.com/theodorosploumis/55a23c2f63d88f3167f0)
- [bash script with Git](https://gist.github.com/theodorosploumis/6a43dadd5fc0dddc350f) (recommended)